# Creating columns in df with day and hour of week based on value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create 2 columns based of a column that contains numerical values.

```
  Value 
    0
    4
    10
    24
    null
    49

Expected Output:
  Value           Day      Hour
    0           Sunday   12:00am
    4           Sunday   4:00am
    10          Sunday   10:00am
    24          Monday   12:00am
    null        No Day    No Time
    49          Tuesday   1:00am
    Continued.....
```

Code I am trying out:

```
    value = df.value.unique()
    Sunday_Starting_Point = pd.to_datetime('Sunday 2015') 
    (Sunday_Starting_Point + pd.to_timedelta(Value, 'h')).dt.strftime('%A %I:%M%P')
```

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think unique values are not necessary, you can use 2 times `dt.strftime` for 2 columns with `replace` with `NaT` values:

```
Sunday_Starting_Point = pd.to_datetime('Sunday 2015') 
x = pd.to_numeric(df.Value, errors='coerce')
s = Sunday_Starting_Point + pd.to_timedelta(x, unit='h')
df['Day'] = s.dt.strftime('%A').replace('NaT','No Day')
df['Hour'] = s.dt.strftime('%I:%M%p').replace('NaT','No Time')
print (df)
   Value      Day     Hour
0    0.0   Sunday  12:00AM
1    4.0   Sunday  04:00AM
2   10.0   Sunday  10:00AM
3   24.0   Monday  12:00AM
4    NaN   No Day  No Time
5   49.0  Tuesday  01:00AM
```

Comment: Thanks, when I try I receive value error of ValueError: unit abbreviation w/o a number @jezrael

Comment: @Chris90 - It seems some non numeric values, can you check if working `s = Sunday_Starting_Point + pd.to_timedelta(df.Value, unit='h', errors='coerce')` instead `s = Sunday_Starting_Point + pd.to_timedelta(df.Value, unit='h')`

Comment: Thanks, it runs, but it gives same value of Sunday for Day and 12:00AM for Hour for every row

Comment: @Chris90 - It seems non numeric values, how working `x = pd.to_numeric(df.Value, errors='coerce')
s = Sunday_Starting_Point + pd.to_timedelta(x, unit='h')` ?

Comment: Yeah this seems to populate and checks with what I am getting, thanks for helping to verify!